# awk: extract string from a field

Tags: shell-script, awk, gawk

in the input fields are separated by pipe sign:

```
CCCC|Sess C1|s1 DA=yy07:@##;/u/t/we
DDDDD|Sess C2|s4 DB=yy8:@##;/u/ba
```

I want to get output where last field is changed (extracted only what is between first = and : in this field

expected output is:

```
CCCC|Sess C1|yy07
DDDDD|Sess C2|yy8
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to get output where last field is changed"? What exactly defines the expected output? Is it the part before the second `|`, plus the part between `=` and `:`? Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: output columns are separated also with | (pipe) - only in the last column I need to print only what is between first = and first : in original last column

Answer (score 8):

standard `awk` is not very  good at extracting data out of fields based on patterns. Some options include:

- `split()` to split the text into an array based on specified delimiters.
- `match()` which sets the `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` variables to indicate where  the match occurred, and then use `subtr()` to extract the matched portion.

So here:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '
  split($3, a, /[=:]/) >= 2 {print $1, $2, a[2]}' < file.txt
```

So returns the portion between the first and second occurrence of a `=` or `:` in `$3`.

Or:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '
  match($3, /=[^:]*/) {
    print $1, $2, substr($3, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1)
  }' < file.txt
```

GNU `awk` has a `gensub()` extension which brings the functionality of `sed`'s `s` command into `awk`:

```
gawk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '
  $3 ~ /=/ {
    print $1, $2, gensub(/^[^=]*=([^:]*).*/, "\\1", 1, $3)
  }' < file.txt
```

Looks for `=` followed by any number of non-`:`s and extracts  the part after `=`. The problem with `gensub()` is that you can't easily tell if the substitution was successful or not, hence the check that `$3` contains `=` first.

With `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/^\([^|]*|[^|]*|\)[^=|]*=\([^:|]*\).*/\1\2/p' < file.txt
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -F'[|]' -lane 'print "$F[0]|$F[1]|$1" if $F[2] =~ /=([^:]*)/' < file.txt
```

Comment: Damn, you were faster. I tried with gawk: `awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '{print $1,$2,gensub(/^[^=]*=([^:]*).*$/, "\\1", "1", $3)}' < file.txt` which is pretty much the same as your suggestion.

Comment: @rexkogitans, thanks. made me realise that my using of `$3 = gensub(...` as the condition was wrong.

Comment: The OP does not mention a condition for the 3rd column at all. I assume they are all formatted like this, so I suggest to drop the condition for the main block at all.

Comment: @rexkogitans, I've all made them to print only those 3 fields if the 3rd field of input was in the expected format. I'll leave it as is unless the OP clarifies what to do when the input is not in the expected format.

Answer (score 4):

I would try

```
awk -F\|  'BEGIN {OFS="|";} 
   {col=index($3,":"); 
    equ=index($3,"=");
    $3=substr($3,equ+1,col-equ-1); 
    print ; }' se
```

where

- `-F\|` tell awk to use `|` as input separator
- `equ=index($3,"=");` get index of = in third field
- `$3=substr($3,equ+1,col-equ-1);`  do actual substitution

Answer (score 0):

The first sub removes the first sixth characters in field 3 and second sub
removes everything after colon including.

```
awk -F\| '{sub(/.{6}/,"",$3)sub(/:.*/,"")}1' OFS=\| file
```